# Facebook API to get News Feed

Tags: facebook, social-networking

I saw on this page: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/] that the News Feed is now outdated:

News feed (this is an outdated view, does not reflect the News Feed on facebook.com): https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=...

So, what is the replacement technique to obtain a news feed? (I think it is the Open Graph, but what is the simplest way to obtain it?)

Thanks!

Comment: Read on, a little further down the page it says, _“Note: /me/home retrieves an outdated view of the News Feed. This is currently a known issue and we don't have any near term plans to bring them back up into parity.”_

Answer (score 0):

The `me/home` is the best connection to retrieve the information you need. Best thing to do will be to poll the api endpoint every 5 minutes or so.